# appearance of rotation not natural

Tags: keyframes

is there a way to make a rotating sphere roll along a surface and look more natural?
Attached is my blend file with a sample. The sphere is rolling along a surface however, due to the fact that its not at 0 on the X on 0 on the Z it rolls lopsided.*presently, both X & Z are at 30 degrees and must remain there.
I would like the X & Z to remain at 30 Degrees and have only the Y rotating.

https://blend-exchange.com/b/ljNDbR4M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here might be a more general solution to any (straight) path.

I added a Curve::Path, put it at Z=.5m, and rotated along Z to the desired orientation. Add a constraint to the parent sphere to Follow the path created:

[image]

Align or copy the Z axis of the parent sphere to the rotation of the path.  This means you now *only* have to animate the rotation along a *single* axis, so you will not have to calculate any x/y/z combination to get it correct:

[image]

Here's the solution: [image]

And then the coffee break that gave me the eurika moment....

Here's another example where I edited the path to add a curve, and changed only two settings in Follow Path (forward axis is now "-X", and enabled "Follow Curve" so that the Z axis will turn:

[image]

and the example with the curving ball: [image]

Comment: "might use..."... is it a teaser?

Comment: @james_t thanks a bunch. i will try both approaches and get back to you when i'm done.

Answer (score 0):

It took a while for me to catch on to what you were saying, as your file (and no screencaps in your question) didn't make the material markings obvious.  The more time you spend on getting your question clearly posted, the faster and more help you'll get.

You want to keep the relative rotation of the sphere's X & Z:

[image]

What I did was to make a duplicate of your sphere, with *un-rotated* X & Z keyframes.  I then cleared keyframes for the original sphere and parented it to the animated, un-rotated, "sphere.001", hidden and masked from rendering (i.e., invisible).   I think this gets you to what you desire.

[image]

An alternative to parenting would be to add the "Child Of" modifier to the rotated, renderable sphere with keyframes cleared.

The explanation.... uhm, well... ?

Comment: after following your advice, I was able to resolve my issue. In addition to this, I attempted to have the same sphere roll diagonally across the plane. This does not have the desired natural look as the sphere rotates in forward motion while sphere advances diagonally. Can you provide a fix or direction?

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=owdmW0wq" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/owdmW0wq/)

Comment: @nicknikolaidis -- i'll try to take a look later today as I have to prep for visitors here mid-day.  I believe that the trick is to get the animation rotation on the parent correct, and so set up the child (renderable) sphere at proper angle to the parent...?

Comment: @nicknikolaidis -- I added another approach to help out (?) below.